# how to span a button?

Tags: html, button

I am wondering if someone here could help me? 
I want to have a button with two words, "Icelandic" at the top and "Toys below".
But I haven't managed how to do it.

```
 <p><a href="Icl-Toys.htm" class='button' >Icelandic Toys</a></p><br>
```

My Css:

```
.button {
border: 2px solid #0a3c59;
background: #f7f9fa;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ffffff), to(#f7f9fa));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #f7f9fa);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #f7f9fa);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #f7f9fa);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #f7f9fa);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #f7f9fa 100%);
padding: 11.5px 23px;
-webkit-border-radius: 6px;
-moz-border-radius: 6px;
border-radius: 6px;
-webkit-box-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 1px 0, inset rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 1px 0;
-moz-box-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 1px 0, inset rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 1px 0;
box-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 1px 0, inset rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 1px 0;
text-shadow: #7ea4bd 0 1px 0;
color: #06426c;
font-size: 15px;
font-family: helvetica, serif;
text-decoration: none;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can move the borders to the P, and set it to a fixed width, and it will break more gracefully.

No extra markup or positioning needed.

```
 .button {
   color: #06426c;
   font-size: 15px;
   font-family: helvetica, serif;
   text-decoration: none;
   vertical-align: middle;
 }

 p { 
   width: 50px;
   text-align: center;
   border: 2px solid #0a3c59;
   background: #f7f9fa;
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ffffff), to(#f7f9fa));
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #f7f9fa);
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #f7f9fa);
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #f7f9fa);
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #f7f9fa);
   background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #f7f9fa 100%);
   padding: 11.5px 23px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
   border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 1px 0, inset rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 1px 0;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 1px 0, inset rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 1px 0;
   box-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 1px 0, inset rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 1px 0;
   text-shadow: #7ea4bd 0 1px 0;
 }
```

demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/k2oostzq/2/

**Option 2**

If you don't want fixed width buttons, or they are dynamic, you can use the `<br>` tag with this code, and swap in an inline-block display for the p.

html has added br:

```
  <p><a href="Icl-Toys.htm" class='button'>Icelandic<br>Toys</a></p>
```

css:

```
 .button {
   color: #06426c;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: helvetica, serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: middle;    
}

p { 
   display: inline-block;
   text-align: center;   
   border: 2px solid #0a3c59;
   background: #f7f9fa;
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ffffff), to(#f7f9fa));
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #f7f9fa);
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #f7f9fa);
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #f7f9fa);
   background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #f7f9fa);
   background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #f7f9fa 100%);
   padding: 11.5px 23px;
   -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
   -moz-border-radius: 6px;
   border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 1px 0, inset rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 1px 0;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 1px 0, inset rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 1px 0;
  box-shadow: rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 1px 0, inset rgba(255,255,255,0.4) 0 1px 0;
 text-shadow: #7ea4bd 0 1px 0;
 }
```

demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/tL2dc2ov/1/

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what u need. Try running the code snippet there to see the result

```css
p{
width:2px;
}
```

```html
<p><a href="Icl-Toys.htm" class='button' >Icelandic Toys</a></p><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can alternatively put it into a div like so: http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/32/

(this way you wont need to fiddle with pixels of words and whatnot.

```
<div class="button1">
    <a href="Icl-Toys.htm" class='' >Icelandic<br/>Toys</a>
</div>


.button1 a {
    text-decoration:none;
}

.button1 {
display:inline-block;
text-align:center;    
...the rest of your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: table-caption;` to achieve this effect.

```css
.button {
  border: 2px solid #0a3c59;
  background: #f7f9fa;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#ffffff), to(#f7f9fa));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #f7f9fa);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #f7f9fa);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #f7f9fa);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #f7f9fa);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff 0%, #f7f9fa 100%);
  padding: 11.5px 23px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0 1px 0, inset rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0 1px 0;
  -moz-box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0 1px 0, inset rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0 1px 0;
  box-shadow: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0 1px 0, inset rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4) 0 1px 0;
  text-shadow: #7ea4bd 0 1px 0;
  color: #06426c;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: helvetica, serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
  
  /* New Style */
  display: table-caption;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <a href="#" class='button'>Icelandic Toys</a>
</p>
<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

add `line-height:xxpx; /*Edit xx to your values in px.*/` property and add a `<br>` in between Icelandic`<br>`Toys.